# Ripple effect does not work when loading `materializecss` dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, materialize

As described in the title, the ripple effect does not work when loading `materializecss` dynamically. The chrome dev tool tells that the following two HTML produce the same DOM tree.

Is there anything wrong with my implementation of dynamically importing `materializecss`?

Here are 2 pieces of the reproducible HTML code (you can try them at https://jsbin.com/ :

---

#### Working Sample (click and hold on the button shows correct ripple effect):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<link rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@materializecss/materialize@1.1.0-alpha/dist/css/materialize.min.css">

<script></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@materializecss/materialize@1.1.0-alpha"></script>

<a class="waves-effect waves-light btn">button</a>
```

---

#### NOT Working (click and hold on the button shows no ripple effect):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<link rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@materializecss/materialize@1.1.0-alpha/dist/css/materialize.min.css">

<script>
  let script = document.createElement('script')
  script.src = 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@materializecss/materialize@1.1.0-alpha'
  document.head.append(script)
</script>

<a class="waves-effect waves-light btn">button</a>
```

---

However, using `document.write()` temporarily solves this problem, but I don't want to use this API since this is not ***flexible***.

---

*Please try not to include another JS library to solve this problem!*

Answer (score 0):

Found the reason. It was because the `Waves` library added a `DOMContentLoaded` event listener which runs `Waves.init()`, but somehow this was not triggered when loading js library dynamically.

Solution: run `Waves.init()` manually